# Keras model on android

Tags: android, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I would like to implement a Real Time object detection on Android, using neural networks. I followed this tutorial:

https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Real-Time-Object-Recognition-part-one/

I don't have any Android experience. Can someone provide some preliminary directions?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.
First install gnuroot Debian.
Then You can install Theano, Keras, NumPy, SciPy and others.
As I know and checked there is no way to install Tensorflow on Android.
Regards
Wojtas